# Discord.py 2.0 interactions how to add reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.tree.command()
@app_commands.describe(question="Give a title")
async def poll(interaction: discord.Interaction, question: str, choice_a: str = None, choice_b: str = None,
                 choice_c: str = None):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{choice_a}\n{choice_b}\n{choice_c}\n",
                        type="rich")

    message = await interaction.response.send_message(f"**{question}**", embed=emb)

    await message.add_reaction('')
```

Hello this is my code i want to add reaction but this doesn't working.

Also i tried:

```
await interaction.add_reaction('')
await interaction.message.add_reaction('')
```

Comment: What is the actual issue, and what happened when you tried to use add_reaction and message.add_reaction? We need more details to find out what your issue is.

Comment: Giving error:
** discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'poll' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction' **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await interaction.response.send_message()` always returns `None`

You can get around this by using `await interaction.channel.send()` which returns `discord.Message` and therefore you are able to `add_reaction()`

```
    message = await interaction.channel.send(f"**{question}**", embed=emb)

    await message.add_reaction('')
```

Late, but there is a better way of doing this. Using `interaction.original_response` we can get the `interactionMessage` object and add reaction from there.

```
await interaction.response.send_message(f"**{question}**", embed=emb)
msg = await interaction.original_response()
await msg.add_reaction('')
```